# Есть ли в Python 3.5 хоть какая-то возможность читать dbf-файлы?

Tags: dbf, python-3.5

Имеется база данных в формате DBF. Если точнее, то это база данных 1с 7.7 (т.е., фактически, это база FoxPro). В ней есть таблицы, в которых надо просто выбирать строки по некоторому очень простому критерию и возвращать их в виде списка. Начал изучать документацию, и тут выяснилось, что средств чтения dbf-файлов в Python 3.5 фактически нет. Эксперименты с библиотекой dbf провалились:

```
table = dbf.Table('SC8454.dbf') # работает, однако уже следующая строка
for item in table: # выдаст исключение 'E:\1\sklad_2006\SC8454.dbf is closed; record 0 is unavailable'
    print(item)
```

Подскажите, может быть я ошибаюсь, и в Python 3.5 все-таки имеются какие-либо надежные средства читать dbf-файлы?

Comment: а там точно валидный dbf файл? Пробовали сторонними утилитами открыть?

Comment: Файл валидный, т.к. база 1С рабочая. Но я нашел решение. Не очень то, что я хотел по функциональности: нет возможности использовать sql-запросы. Но зато под Py3.5 работает без каких-либо проблем. Пакет dbfread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед for нужна строка: `table.open()`

```
table = dbf.Table('SC8454.dbf')
table.open()
for item in table:
    print(item)
```

Comment: @0xdb, форматирование сделало синтаксис кода невалидным, хотя судя по коду ответа, там и так уже была ошибка )

Comment: @gil9red спасибо  за замечание, поправте сообшение.